# Get rid of Prompt Dialog when printing with Java

Tags: java, printing

In this piece of code:

```
//Staff
pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
pj.setPrintable(graphComponent);
try {
    pj.print();  // This is the function in question !!
} catch (PrinterException e2) {
    System.out.println(e2);
}
//Staff
```

The function print of the job printer, leads you to

[image: Printing promt]

What I want, is that I give a default name to the file (printing result) without having that prompt.
How can I change that code to get that?

Comment: If the question is about http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html you should state that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your ***pj*** is a **PrinterJob** instance, try calling

```
pj.setJobName("defaultname.pdf");
```